When is a minimal degree linear combination of univariate polynomials a common divisor?
Let $f_1,\dots ,f_n\in A[x]$. Let $\sum_iu_if_i\in \langle f_1,\dots ,f_n\rangle \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ be a minimal degree element. Write $c\in A$ for its top coefficient.
Performing for each $i$ polynomial division, there's some large $N$ such that $$c^N f_i = q_i (\sum_iu_if_i)+r_i.$$ Since $r_i\in \langle f_1,\dots ,f_n\rangle$, minimality ensures it equals zero. Hence $c^Nf_i=q_i(\sum_iu_if_i)$. This doesn't ensure the minimal degree fellow actually divides all of the $f_i$ though.
Is there some simple condition that allows one to reach this conclusion (apart from invertible $c$)?

$A$: field, ring, or other?

Commutative ring

Related question.
